# Reverting an android preference's value when a statement in another thread fails

Tags: android, multithreading, sharedpreferences, revert

I have settings in my app that I allow the user to manipulate using a `PreferenceScreen` with `Preference`s. However, I want to store the settings on a server so that the settings can persist over multiple devices. I have the following code that lets me do this:

```
private void updateSettingOnPrefChange(final Preference pref, final Setting setting) {
    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
            try {
                setting.update(newValue, new Callback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Boolean succeeded) {
                        if (!succeeded) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting failed to update. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //here I need to revert the value of the Preference without again calling the onChangeListener
                        }
                    }
                }, getActivity());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting failed to update. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see in the code the request is being run on a different thread using a custom `Callback` class to clean up based on the result of the call. The issue is the code will have already return true on the main thread.

How can I revert the value of the `Preference` in the callback function (preferably without also calling the onPrefChangeListener function so I don't get  infinite recursion)?

Comment: I think you need to think about your design ... I would first store the value locally, and then trying to upload it on server side ... also, you need to consider what you do when the upload of the value fails, like you would need to retry possibly exponentially ... last but not least, I recommend you to persist and upload the new value only if different than the actual value

Comment: The `Setting` class caches the value locally as well. When the upload fails I want to just alert the user and revert the shared preference (if they want to try again they can). Good tip on checking if they are equal though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the OnPreferenceClickListener instead of OnPreferenceChangeListener to listen for user taps on the setting field and then make your rpc request accordingly. If you have to update the value (in the case of a server failure) you can change the setting without firing the click listener and having the infinite loop.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceClickListener(android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener)